# Weird Results on MySQL SELECT Statement with ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, select, sql-order-by

I'm getting weird results on a MySQL SELECT statement that uses ORDER BY my_column ASC.

It's ordering the results the way a "computer" would order them, instead of a human:

- Item F: 241.565853
- Item B: 25.310854
- Item D: 25.397155
- Item C: 260.252356
- Item A: 27.7740
- Item E: 271.774058

How do I get it to ORDER BY in the correct manner? My SELECT statement has a couple LEFT JOINS-- not sure if that would make a difference.

Any suggestions on how to correct this problem?

Comment: Whats the data type of column you are trying to use order by on? If possible paste table meta data/your query

Comment: Hi Adnan Bhatti, Thank you for the message. I order by offenses_per_sq_mile DESC which is calculated from: ( COUNT(*) / ((wp_neighborhood_area.neighborhood_area_in_sq_meters /1000) * 0.000386102159) ) AS offenses_per_sq_mile . The column, neighborhood_area_in_sq_meters, is int(10). Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
ORDER BY ABS(my_column) ASC
```

Comment: np, one thing there though, as function returns an absolute value, if you have negative numbers, this hack might not be suitable.

Comment: Thank you for the follow-up message. In my situation, it will work great as the number will always be positive. Thank you for the warning, though!

Answer (score 0):

The column you're ordering by is most likely a string-based (varchar, text, etc) datatype. You're seeing lexically-correct ordering for such a datatype. Change the column to use a numeric datatype, or (less-preferably, because *why are you storing a numeric value as a string*) cast the column to a numeric type and perform the sort on that cast.

Comment: Hi Michael, Thanks you for your message. I "over-simplified" my example. I have a numeric data type. Dmitry F helped me solve it. But, thank you for taking the time to help me.